# Using Protractor with Extended HTML Markup (x-ng and data-ng)

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-e2e

I'm using protractor to test e2e with my Angular.js app. I am able to grab elements by ng-model using:

```
element(by.model('ctrl.someModel')).sendKeys('abc');
```

However, it only works if the model is "ng-model", and not using the strict markup extenders like "data-ng-model" or "x-ng-model".

Does anyone know a way to do it with the HTML extenders?

Answer (score 1):

`data-ng-model` is [covered](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L428-L444) by `by.model` locator. `protractor` has even a [test](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/69404aaee833f41de62eaa3112957659d21094a3/spec/basic/locators_spec.js#L108-L117) for it:

```
it('should find inputs with alternate attribute forms', function() {
  var letterList = element(by.id('letterlist'));
  expect(letterList.getText()).toBe('');

  element(by.model('check.w')).click();
  expect(letterList.getText()).toBe('w');

  element(by.model('check.x')).click();
  expect(letterList.getText()).toBe('wx');
});
```

where `check.w` and `check.x` models [are defined as](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/69404aaee833f41de62eaa3112957659d21094a3/testapp/form/form.html#L52-L53):

```
<input ng:model="check.w" ng-true-value="'w'" type="checkbox"/> W
<input data-ng-model="check.x" ng-true-value="'x'" type="checkbox"/> X
```

FYI, under-the-hood, `by.model()` uses [`findByModel` "client-side" function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L428-L444) that constructs a set of CSS selectors for the `['ng-', 'ng_', 'data-ng-', 'x-ng-', 'ng\\:']` prefixes:

```
[ng-model="modelname"]
[data-ng-model="modelname"]
 ...
```